# Bezier and b-spline arc-length algorithm giving me problems

Tags: swift, bezier, numerical-integration

I'm having a bit of a problem calculating the arc-length of my bezier and b-spline curves. I've been banging my head against this for several days, and I think I'm almost there, but can't seem to get it exactly right. I'm developing in Swift, but I think its syntax is clear enough that anyone who knows C/C++ would be able to read it. If not, please let me know and I'll try to translate it into C/C++.

I've checked my implementations against several sources over and over again, and, as far as the algorithms go, they seem to be correct, although I'm not so sure about the B-spline algorithm. Some tutorials use the degree, and some use the order, of the curve in their calculations, and I get really confused. In addition, in using the Gauss-Legendre quadrature, I understand that I'm supposed to sum the integration of the spans, but I'm not sure I'm understanding how to do that correctly. From what I understand, I should be integrating over each knot span. Is that correct?

When I calculate the length of a Bezier curve with the following control polygon, I get 28.2842712474619, while 3D software (Cinema 4D and Maya) tells me the length should be 30.871.

```
let bezierControlPoints = [
    Vector(-10.0, -10.0),
    Vector(0.0, -10.0),
    Vector(0.0, 10.0),
    Vector(10.0, 10.0)
]
```

The length of the b-spline is similarly off. My algorithm produces 5.6062782185353, while it should be 7.437.

```
let splineControlPoints = [
    Vector(-2.0, -1.0),
    Vector(-1.0, 1.0),
    Vector(-0.25, 1.0),
    Vector(0.25, -1.0),
    Vector(1.0, -1.0),
    Vector(2.0, 1.0)
]
```

I'm not a mathematician, so I'm struggling with the math, but I think I have the gist of it.

The Vector class is pretty straight-forwared, but I've overloaded some operators for convenience/legibility which makes the code quite lengthy, so I'm not posting it here. I'm also not including the Gauss-Legendre weights and abscissae. You can download the source and Xcode project from [here](http://ejanne.com/~tigakub/ArcLengthTest.zip) (53K).

Here's my bezier curve class:

```
class Bezier
{
    var c0:Vector
    var c1:Vector
    var c2:Vector
    var c3:Vector

    init(ic0 _ic0:Vector, ic1 _ic1:Vector, ic2 _ic2:Vector, ic3 _ic3:Vector) {
        c0 = _ic0
        c1 = _ic1
        c2 = _ic2
        c3 = _ic3
    }

    // Calculate curve length using Gauss-Legendre quadrature
    func curveLength()->Double {
        let gl = GaussLegendre()
        gl.order = 3    // Good enough for a quadratic polynomial
        let xprime = gl.integrate(a:0.0, b:1.0, closure:{ (t:Double)->Double in return self.dx(atTime:t) })
        let yprime = gl.integrate(a:0.0, b:1.0, closure:{ (t:Double)->Double in return self.dy(atTime:t) })

        return sqrt(xprime*xprime + yprime*yprime)
    }

    // I could vectorize this, but correctness > efficiency

    // The derivative of the x-component
    func dx(atTime t:Double)->Double {
        let tc = (1.0-t)
        let r0 = (3.0 * tc*tc) * (c1.x - c0.x)
        let r1 = (6.0 * tc*t) * (c2.x - c1.x)
        let r2 = (3.0 * t*t) * (c3.x - c2.x)
        return r0 + r1 + r2
    }

    // The derivative of the y-component
    func dy(atTime t:Double)->Double {
        let tc = (1.0-t)
        let r0 = (3.0 * tc*tc) * (c1.y - c0.y)
        let r1 = (6.0 * tc*t) * (c2.y - c1.y)
        let r2 = (3.0 * t*t) * (c3.y - c2.y)
        return r0 + r1 + r2
    }
}
```

Here is my b-spline class:

```
class BSpline
{
    var spanLengths:[Double]! = nil
    var totalLength:Double = 0.0
    var cp:[Vector]
    var knots:[Double]! = nil
    var o:Int = 4

    init(controlPoints:[Vector]) {
        cp = controlPoints
        calcKnots()
    }

    // Method to return length of the curve using Gauss-Legendre numerical integration
    func cacheSpanLengths() {
        spanLengths = [Double]()

        totalLength = 0.0

        let gl = GaussLegendre()
        gl.order = o-1  // The derivative should be quadratic, so o-2 would suffice?

        // Am I doing this right? Piece-wise integration?
        for i in o-1 ..< knots.count-o {
            let t0 = knots[i]
            let t1 = knots[i+1]
            let xprime = gl.integrate(a:t0, b:t1, closure:self.dx)
            let yprime = gl.integrate(a:t0, b:t1, closure:self.dy)
            let spanLength = sqrt(xprime*xprime + yprime*yprime)
            spanLengths.append(spanLength)
            totalLength += spanLength
        }
    }

    // The b-spline basis function
    func basis(i:Int, _ k:Int, _ x:Double)->Double {
        var r:Double = 0.0
        switch k {
            case 0:
                if (knots[i] <= x) && (x <= knots[i+1]) {
                    r = 1.0
                } else {
                    r = 0.0
                }
            default:
                var n0 = x - knots[i]
                var d0 = knots[i+k]-knots[i]
                var b0 = basis(i,k-1,x)

                var n1 = knots[i+k+1] - x
                var d1 = knots[i+k+1]-knots[i+1]
                var b1 = basis(i+1,k-1,x)

                var left = Double(0.0)
                var right = Double(0.0)
                if b0 != 0 && d0 != 0 { left = n0 * b0 / d0 }
                if b1 != 0 && d1 != 0 { right = n1 * b1 / d1 }
                r = left + right
        }
        return r
    }

    // Method to calculate and store the knot vector
    func calcKnots() {

        // The number of knots in the knot vector = number of control points + order (i.e. degree + 1)
        let knotCount = cp.count + o

        knots = [Double]()

        // For an open b-spline where the ends are incident on the first and last control points,
        // the first o knots are the same and the last o knots are the same, where o is the order
        // of the curve.
        var k = 0
        for i in 0 ..< o {
            knots.append(0.0)
        }
        for i in o ..< cp.count {
            k++
            knots.append(Double(k))
        }
        k++
        for i in cp.count ..< knotCount {
            knots.append(Double(k))
        }
    }

    // I could vectorize this, but correctness > efficiency

    // Derivative of the x-component
    func dx(t:Double)->Double {
        var p = Double(0.0)

        let n = o
        for i in 0 ..< cp.count-1 {
            let u0 = knots[i + n + 1]
            let u1 = knots[i + 1]
            let fn = Double(n) / (u0 - u1)
            let thePoint = (cp[i+1].x - cp[i].x) * fn
            let b = basis(i+1, n-1, Double(t))
            p += thePoint * b
        }

        return Double(p)
    }

    // Derivative of the y-component
    func dy(t:Double)->Double {
        var p = Double(0.0)

        let n = o
        for i in 0 ..< cp.count-1 {
            let u0 = knots[i + n + 1]
            let u1 = knots[i + 1]
            let fn = Double(n) / (u0 - u1)
            let thePoint = (cp[i+1].y - cp[i].y) * fn
            let b = basis(i+1, n-1, Double(t))
            p += thePoint * b
        }

        return Double(p)
    }
}
```

And here is my Gauss-Legendre implementation:

```
class GaussLegendre
{
    var order:Int = 5

    init() {
    }

    // Numerical integration of arbitrary function
    func integrate(a _a:Double, b _b:Double, closure f:(Double)->Double)->Double {
        var result = 0.0
        let wgts = gl_weights[order-2]
        let absc = gl_abscissae[order-2]
        for i in 0..<order {
            let a0 = absc[i]
            let w0 = wgts[i]
            result += w0 * f(0.5 * (_b + _a + a0 * (_b - _a)))
        }
        return 0.5 * (_b - _a) * result
    }
}
```

And my main logic:

```
let bezierControlPoints = [
    Vector(-10.0, -10.0),
    Vector(0.0, -10.0),
    Vector(0.0, 10.0),
    Vector(10.0, 10.0)
]

let splineControlPoints = [
    Vector(-2.0, -1.0),
    Vector(-1.0, 1.0),
    Vector(-0.25, 1.0),
    Vector(0.25, -1.0),
    Vector(1.0, -1.0),
    Vector(2.0, 1.0)
]

var bezier = Bezier(controlPoints:bezierControlPoints)
println("Bezier curve length: \(bezier.curveLength())\n")

var spline:BSpline = BSpline(controlPoints:splineControlPoints)
spline.cacheSpanLengths()
println("B-Spline curve length: \(spline.totalLength)\n")
```

## **UPDATE: PROBLEM (PARTIALLY) SOLVED**

Thanks to Mike for his answer!

I verified that I am correctly remapping the numerical integration from the interval a..b to -1..1 for the purposes of Legendre-Gauss quadrature. The math is [here](http://morax.tigakub.com/~tigakub/SplineArcLength/SubstitutionRule.html) (apologies to any real mathematicians out there, it's the best I could do with my long-forgotten calculus).

I've increased the order of the Legendre-Gauss quadrature from 5 to 32 as Mike suggested.

Then after a lot of floundering around in Mathematica, I came back and re-read Mike's code and discovered that my code was **NOT** equivalent to his.

I was taking the square root of the sums of the squared integrals of the derivative components:

[image: WRONG]

when I should have been taking the integral of the magnitudes of the derivative vectors:

[image: RIGHT]

In terms of code, in my Bezier class, instead of this:

```
// INCORRECT
func curveLength()->Double {
    let gl = GaussLegendre()
    gl.order = 3    // Good enough for a quadratic polynomial
    let xprime = gl.integrate(a:0.0, b:1.0, closure:{ (t:Double)->Double in return self.dx(atTime:t) })
    let yprime = gl.integrate(a:0.0, b:1.0, closure:{ (t:Double)->Double in return self.dy(atTime:t) })

    return sqrt(xprime*xprime + yprime*yprime)
}
```

I should have written this:

```
// CORRECT
func curveLength()->Double {
    let gl = GaussLegendre()
    gl.order = 32
    return = gl.integrate(a:0.0, b:1.0, closure:{ (t:Double)->Double in
        let x = self.dx(atTime:t)
        let y = self.dy(atTime:t)
        return sqrt(x*x + y*y)
    })
}
```

My code calculates the arc length as: 3.59835872777095
Mathematica: 3.598358727834686

So, my result is pretty close. Interestingly, there is a discrepancy between a plot in Mathematica of my test Bezier curve, and the same rendered by Cinema 4D, which would explain why the arc lengths calculated by Mathematica and Cinema 4D are different as well. I think I trust Mathematica to be more correct, though.

In my B-Spline class, instead of this:

```
// INCORRECT
func cacheSpanLengths() {
    spanLengths = [Double]()

    totalLength = 0.0

    let gl = GaussLegendre()
    gl.order = o-1  // The derivative should be quadratic, so o-2 would suffice?

    // Am I doing this right? Piece-wise integration?
    for i in o-1 ..< knots.count-o {
        let t0 = knots[i]
        let t1 = knots[i+1]
        let xprime = gl.integrate(a:t0, b:t1, closure:self.dx)
        let yprime = gl.integrate(a:t0, b:t1, closure:self.dy)
        let spanLength = sqrt(xprime*xprime + yprime*yprime)
        spanLengths.append(spanLength)
        totalLength += spanLength
    }
}
```

I should have written this:

```
// CORRECT
func cacheSpanLengths() {
    spanLengths = [Double]()

    totalLength = 0.0

    let gl = GaussLegendre()
    gl.order = 32

    // Am I doing this right? Piece-wise integration?
    for i in o-1 ..< knots.count-o {
        let t0 = knots[i]
        let t1 = knots[i+1]
        let spanLength = gl.integrate(a:t0, b:t1, closure:{ (t:Double)->Double in
            let x = self.dx(atTime:t)
            let y = self.dy(atTime:t)
            return sqrt(x*x + y*y)
        })
        spanLengths.append(spanLength)
        totalLength += spanLength
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the B-Spline math is not as straight-forward, and I haven't been able to test it in Mathematica as easily as the Bezier math, so I'm not entirely sure my code is working, even with the above changes. I will post another update when I verify it.

## **UPDATE 2: PROBLEM SOLVED**

Eureka, I discovered an off-by one error in my code to calculate the B-Spline derivative.

Instead of

```
    // Derivative of the x-component
    func dx(t:Double)->Double {
        var p = Double(0.0)

        let n = o // INCORRECT (should be one less)
        for i in 0 ..< cp.count-1 {
            let u0 = knots[i + n + 1]
            let u1 = knots[i + 1]
            let fn = Double(n) / (u0 - u1)
            let thePoint = (cp[i+1].x - cp[i].x) * fn
            let b = basis(i+1, n-1, Double(t))
            p += thePoint * b
        }

        return Double(p)
    }

    // Derivative of the y-component
    func dy(t:Double)->Double {
        var p = Double(0.0)

        let n = o // INCORRECT (should be one less_
        for i in 0 ..< cp.count-1 {
            let u0 = knots[i + n + 1]
            let u1 = knots[i + 1]
            let fn = Double(n) / (u0 - u1)
            let thePoint = (cp[i+1].y - cp[i].y) * fn
            let b = basis(i+1, n-1, Double(t))
            p += thePoint * b
        }

        return Double(p)
    }
```

I should have written

```
    // Derivative of the x-component
    func dx(t:Double)->Double {
        var p = Double(0.0)

        let n = o-1 // CORRECT
        for i in 0 ..< cp.count-1 {
            let u0 = knots[i + n + 1]
            let u1 = knots[i + 1]
            let fn = Double(n) / (u0 - u1)
            let thePoint = (cp[i+1].x - cp[i].x) * fn
            let b = basis(i+1, n-1, Double(t))
            p += thePoint * b
        }

        return Double(p)
    }

    // Derivative of the y-component
    func dy(t:Double)->Double {
        var p = Double(0.0)

        let n = o-1 // CORRECT
        for i in 0 ..< cp.count-1 {
            let u0 = knots[i + n + 1]
            let u1 = knots[i + 1]
            let fn = Double(n) / (u0 - u1)
            let thePoint = (cp[i+1].y - cp[i].y) * fn
            let b = basis(i+1, n-1, Double(t))
            p += thePoint * b
        }

        return Double(p)
    }
```

My code now calculates the length of the B-Spline curve as 6.87309971722132.
Mathematica: 6.87309884638438.

It's probably not scientifically precise, but good enough for me.

Comment: The correct length for the Cubic Bezier Curve that goes through (-10, -10), (0, -10), (10, 0), (10, 10) is 29.90575 not 30.871 (I think).  I used the 30.871 value in unit tests for my own code and couldn't work out why there was a problem.   You can play with the applet here:  http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#arclengthapprox to see (I used the points (60, 60), (100, 60), (140, 100) and (140, 140) (scaled up by a factor of 4 and translated the origin to (100, 100) to be able to see the curve on the graph).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Legendre-Gauss procedure is specifically defined for the interval [-1,1], whereas Beziers and B-Splines are defined over [0,1], so that's a simple conversion and at least while you're trying to make sure your code does the right thing, easy to bake in instead of supplying a dynamic interval (as you say, accuracy over efficiency. Once it works, we can worry about optimising)

So, given weights `W` and abscissae `A` (both of same length `n`), you'd do:

```
z = 0.5
for i in 1..n
  w = W[i]
  a = A[i]
  t = z * a + z
  sum += w * arcfn(t, xpoints, ypoints)
return z * sum
```

with the pseudo-code assuming list indexing from 1. The `arcfn` would be defined as:

```
arcfn(t, xpoints, ypoints):
  x = derive(xpoints, t)
  y = derive(ypoints, t)
  c = x*x + y*y
  return sqrt(c)
```

But that part looks right already.

Your derivatives look correct too, so the main question is: "are you using enough slices in your Legendre-Gauss quadrature?". Your code suggests you're using only 5 slices, which isn't nearly enough to get a good result. Using http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/legendre-gauss.html as term data, you generally want a set for `n` of 16 or higher (for cubic Bezier curves, 24 is generally safe, although still underperformant for curves with cusps or lots of inflections).

I can recommend taking the "unit test" approach here: test your bezier and bspline code (separately) for known base and derivative values. Do those check out? One problem ruled out. On to your LG code: if you perform Legendre-Gauss on a parametric function for a straight line using:

```
fx(t) = t
fy(t) = t
fx'(t) = 1
fy'(t) = 1
```

over interval t=[0,1], we know the length should be *exactly* the square root of 2, and the derivatives are the simplest possible. If those work, do a non-linear test using:

```
fx(t) = sin(t)
fy(t) = cos(t)
fx'(t) = cos(t)
fy'(t) = -sin(t)
```

over interval t=[0,1]; we know the length should be *exactly* 1. Does your LG implementation yield the correct value? Another problem ruled out. If it doesn't, check your weights and abscissae. Do they match the ones from the linked page (generated with a verifiably correct Mathematica program, so pretty much guaranteed to be correct)? Are you using enough slices? Bump the number up to 10, 16, 24, 32; increasing the number of slices will show a stabilising summation, where adding more slices doesn't change digits before the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, etc decimal point as you increase the count.

Are the curves you're testing with known to be problematic curves? Plot them, do they have cusps or lots of inflections? That's going to be a problem for LG, try simpler curves to see if the values you get back for those, at least, are correct.

Finally, check your types: Are you using the highest precision possible datatype? 32 bit floats are going to run into mysteriously disappearing FPU and wonderful rounding errors at the values we need to use when doing LG with a reasonable number of slices.